# Meets and joins in the lattice of partitions

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be a set. A *partition* is a collection $P\subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ such that

1. $\bigcup P = X$, and
2. $p\neq q \in P$ implies $p\cap q = \emptyset$.

For $P, Q\in \text{Part}(X)$ we say $P\leq Q$ if for every $q\in Q$ there is $p\in P$ such that $p\subseteq q$. Let $\text{Part}(X)$ denote the collection of all partitions of $X$. It turns out that $(\text{Part}(X),\leq)$ is a complete lattice.

Given $P,Q\in\text{Part}(X)$, what is the explicit construction of $P\vee Q$ and $P\wedge Q$?

Comment: Actually, $\subseteq$ is not the order on this lattice. It is a more complicated rule - $P_1\leq P_2$ if, for all $p\in P_1$ there is a $q\in P_2$ with $p\subseteq q$. This is the "refinement" lattice.

Comment: That's right - will correct!

Comment: The join is the complicated part. The meet is: $P\wedge Q=\{p\cap q\mid p\in P, q\in Q,p\cap q\neq \emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: for the lower bound, we need a partition to be a refinement of *both* elements. Consider the partition formed by taking all nonempty intersections of blocks in P and Q.

Edit: thanks for ThomasAndrews pointing out my error.

For an upper bound, we need a partition of which P and Q are both refinements. Consider the partition who's blocks are formed iteratively as follows: start by taking a block $p\in P$ and forming $b_0=p\cup_q q$, where the union is taken over all $q\in Q$ which intersect nontrivially with $p$.

Then create $b_1=b_0\cup_{p'}p'$, where again the union is taken over all $p'\in P$ which intersects nontrivially with $b_0$. Then from $b_1$ create $b_2$ by throwing in more blocks of Q which intersect nontrivially, and continue the process until it stabilizes. This gives one block of the larger partition; repeat this process until all elements are in some block, which will give you a final partition.

Comment: But that $p\cup_q q$ is still not enough - you'll need to then add any $p'$ that intersect any of the $q$, and then again, any $q$ that intersect those $p'$, etc.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes you're right, sorry. Did not think ahead far enough, will edit.