# Explicit construction of the join of an arbitrary set in the lattice of partitions?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be a set.
A partition of $A$ is a collection $\pi$ of nonempty subsets of $A$ such that

1. $\bigcup\pi = A$, and
2. $x\cap y = \varnothing$ for distinct $x$ and $y$ in $\pi$.

Let $P(A)$ be the collection of partitions of $A$,
and let $\lesssim$ be the refinement order on $P(A)$,
which for any $\pi$ and $\sigma$ in $P(A)$ is defined by
$\pi\lesssim\sigma$ if and only if for each $x$ in $\pi$ there is a $y$ in $\sigma$
such that $x\subseteq y$.

$P(A)$ ordered by refinement is a lattice,
and an explicit construction of the join $\pi\vee\sigma$
of any two partitions $\pi$ and $\sigma$ in $P(A)$
has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064808/meets-and-joins-in-the-lattice-of-partitions):
call any blocks $x$ and $y$ in $\pi$ or $\sigma$ *equivalent* if and only if
there are $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ in $\pi\cup\sigma$
such that $x = w_1$
and $y = w_n$
and $w_i\cap w_{i+1}\neq\varnothing$ for $i=1,\ldots,i-1$,
then this defines an equivalence relation $\equiv$ on $\pi\cup\sigma$
and each block in $\pi\vee\sigma$ equals the union of an equivalence class of $\equiv$.

This explicit construction of the join of two partitions extends to
one for arbitrary nonempty subsets $S$ of $P(A)$
by allowing the $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ to be elements in $\bigcup S$.

**Question:**
Does this explicit construction of the join of a subset $S$ of $P(A)$
extend to the case where $S$ is empty, and if so, how?

It is well-known that $P(A)$ ordered by refinement is a complete lattice,
so the join $\bigvee\varnothing$ of the empty set exists,
and that it equals the partition consisting of singleton sets $\{a\}$, $a\in A$.

For nonempty subsets $S$ of $P(A)$,
applying the above construction,
I can write a block in $\bigvee S$
as the union of the equivalence class $[\pi]_\equiv$ of an element $\pi$ in $\bigcup S$.
But if $S$ is empty,
then there are no $\pi$ in $\bigcup S$
to construct an equivalence class $[\pi]_\equiv$ for.
Is there a way to make the above construction work when $S$ is empty?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, now, that this can be done as follows.

For each $a$ in $A$,
let $[a]$ be the collection of sets $\{a\}$ and all $w$ in $\bigcup S$
for which there are $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ in $\bigcup S$,
where $n$ is a positive integer,
such that $w_1 = \{a\}$,
$w_i\cap w_{i+1}$ is nonempty,
and $w_n = w$.
Then $\bigvee S$ is the collection of sets $\bigcup[a]$, $a\in A$.